# How to sort projects in visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sorting, project, solution

How can you sort your projects within a solution folder.
I have a solution with 3 solution folders and in there I have several class libraries but they don't seem to be sorted by name but by creation.

Is there a way to sort them by name? (from within vs 2008, not by changing the sln manually)

Regards,
M

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://blog.catenalogic.com/post/Sort-Visual-Studio-2008-Projects-alphabetically-inside-Solution-Folders.aspx) post. Quote:

> It is a known bug that Visual Studio
>   does not sort projects alphabetically
>   when the projects are located inside
>   Solution Folders. Since I am working
>   on pretty large solutions (more than
>   20 projects for 1 solution), and I
>   like to order the projects via
>   Solution Folders, this is a very
>   irritating bug.
>
> However, I accidently found the
>   solution to this problem. Follow the
>   steps below to sort your projects
>   alphabetically inside Solution
>   Folders.
>
> Right-click on a project and select
>   rename (or simple select a project,
>   wait 1 second, and click it again or
>   press F2). Don’t change the name,
>   simply select another project.

Comment: That's right but if you close and reopen the solution afterwards it's messed up again. This blog gives the hint on how to keep the changed order: https://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/sort-projects-alphabetically-in-visual-studio/. Collapse the containing solution folder before closing the solution.

Comment: The Chairman's little trick also fixes Visual Studio's annoying feature [read: bug] of displaying the folders in incorrect order inside a project when they are added. They stick like that if you leave them expanded when closing and re-opening the solution.
Simply collapsing the project, closing the solution, then re-opening the solution fixed the problem.